# UICollectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath doesn't get cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a simple collectionView, and with `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` I change cell's background color.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

All works fine, but if I select a cell, scroll the list (my selected cell go out of screen) and I select another, in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` my "cell" variable is nil.
Why?

NB: only when the selected cell go out of screen

Comment: Have you added any gesture on parent view?

Comment: When you scroll, cells will get reused, so they lose their background color.

Comment: You will have to set a property in cell's model that tells the delegate methods that this cell is selected. So that even if tableview reloads, the cell should still be still selected.

Comment: Show you `cellForRow` then we can help more.

Comment: if any gesture is there then please remove it

Answer (score 0):

**Simply logic behind cell selected and deselected in proper way:**

> ViewController.h

```
 int selectedIndex;
```

> ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      selectedIndex = -1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
        static NSString *identifier = @"CollectionCell";
        WalletCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
        {
               cell.selected = YES;
               cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        else
        {
               cell.selected = NO;
               cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
          return cell;
  }


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
       UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 }
```

Comment: i've tried. If I select the first cell, scroll down, select the last and come up again, I see the first cell already width background. I scroll again for put out of screen the first cell, return at top and finally this is without background.
Seems that I need more then one graphics update

Comment: means you want to select multiple cell in collection view? suppose first you select first cell and background will change to red after scrolling you select last cell and background will change to red color.